# In Python, why is list[] automatically global?

Tags: python, list, global, python-2.7

This is a weird behavior.

Try this :

```
rep_i=0
print "rep_i is" , rep_i
def test():
  global rep_i #without Global this gives error but list , dict , and others don't
  if rep_i==0:
    print "Testing Integer %s" % rep_i
    rep_i=1
  return "Done"

rep_lst=[1,2,3]
 

def test2():
  if rep_lst[0]==1:
    print "Testing List %s" % rep_lst
  return "Done"


if __name__=="__main__":
  test()
  test2()
```

Why list do not need to declare global? are they automatically global?

I find it really weird, I use list most of the time and I don't even use global at all to us them as global...

Comment: It has nothing to do with the type, and nothing to do with how it is accessed. It has everything to do with **not assigning** to the intended-global name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It isn't automatically global.

However, there's a difference between `rep_i=1` and `rep_lst[0]=1` - the former rebinds the name `rep_i`, so `global` is needed to prevent creation of a local slot of the same name. In the latter case, you're just modifying an existing, global object, which is found by regular name lookup (changing a list entry is like calling a member function on the list, it's not a name rebinding).

To test it out, try assigning `rep_lst=[]` in `test2` (i.e. set it to a fresh list). Unless you declare `rep_lst` `global`, the effects won't be visible outside `test2` because a local slot of the same name is created and shadows the global slot.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to use `global` if you are assigning to the global name.  Without `global`, an assignment creates a new local.

There's nothing special about how `global` applies to a list—`global` simply influences scope and name resolution.

Comment: So thats mean if i append something to the list it will fail? gonna try.

Comment: No, it won't fail. It's only if you assign to the global name, what is known as re-binding. So `rep_lst = []` will create a new list and bind a new local variable to it. But `rep_lst.append()` will look up the name `rep_lst`, find it in the global namespace, and call a method on it.

Comment: So , best practice is to put global on vars which suppose to be used as global? I always uses global lists without defining global at all (i dont ever know it is necessary until i did it with integer).

Answer (score 5):

There is an error in python called `UnboundLocalError` which often confuses newcomers. The confusing thing is: *future* assignment **does** change the way a variable is looked up.

When the interpreter sees a variable name for the first time, it looks ahead to the end of current code block, and if you don't have an assignment to it anywhere within the same block of code, the interpreter considers it global. If you do, however, then it is considered local, and any reference to it before assignment generates an `UnboundLocalError`. That's the error you got. That's why you need to declare `global rep_i`. If you did not assign `rep_i`, you wouldn't need this line.

Also, this has nothing to do with variable type. Also, assigning or appending an item to the list (which you probably meant to do, but did not) is not assignment of the list itself, it is essentially calling a method on a list object, which is different from assignment: assignment creates a new object (possibly under a name that already exists), while manipulating a list just changes an existing list.
You can try:

```
In [1]: # It won't work with small integers, as they are cached singletons in CPython

In [2]: a = 123123

In [3]: id (a)
Out[3]: 9116848

In [4]: a = 123123

In [5]: id(a)
Out[5]: 9116740

In [6]: # See, it changed

In [7]: # Now with lists

In [8]: l = [1,2,3]

In [9]: id(l)
Out[9]: 19885792

In [10]: l[1] = 2

In [11]: id(l)
Out[11]: 19885792

In [12]: # See, it is the same

In [13]: # But if i reassign the list, even to the same value

In [14]: l = [2,2,3]

In [15]: id(l)
Out[15]: 19884272
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example that demonstrates that a non `list`/`dict` variable is available in a subroutine, and the problem is, as everyone says, the act of `rebinding` in your original code sample:

```
x = 1
def test():
    y = x + 1
    print y
test()
```

You'll see this prints out `2`, despite `x` not being declared global.

Answer (score 3):

If you had assigned a new value to `rep_lst` inside of `test2` (not just to one of its elements, as you did) it would not work without the `global` flag. In Python, if you do not assign to a variable inside a function it will look for that variable in in more global scopes until it finds it.

For example, in this code segment I define the list both globally and inside of `example()`. Since the variable in `example()` is closer in scope to `example2()` than the global one is, it is what will be used.

```
x = ["out"]

def example():
    x = ["in"]
    def example2():
        print x # will print ["in"]
```

This has nothing to do with lists, but is the behaviour of any variable in Python.