# Modify global list inside a function

Tags: python, function, global-variables

First of all, I understand that I can use `global` statement to access global variables. But somehow I was able to modify a global list without `global` like below:

```
def func1(nums):
    nums = [4,5,6]

nums = [1,2,3]
func1(nums)
print nums # print [1,2,3]

def func2(nums):
    nums[0] = 4
    nums[1] = 5
    nums[2] = 6

nums = [1,2,3]
func2(nums)
print nums # print [4,5,6]
```

After trying func2, I realized that I can always access global list in a function if I specify the index:

```
def func3(nums):
    nums[:] = [4,5,6]

nums = [1,2,3]
func3(nums)
print nums # print [4,5,6]
```

Is it because Python automatically goes trying to match a global variable if a function variable is used before definition?

Comment: What exactly is your question? `nums = ` is a local assignment, unrelated to the outer scope, whereas in the other cases you're modifying the same object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, why is list\[\] automatically global?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329499/in-python-why-is-list-automatically-global)

Answer (score 13):

> I understand that I can use global statement to access global variables

Your understanding is wrong. You can always *access* a global variable as long as you don't have a local variable of the same name. You only need the `global` statement when you are going to *change* what object a variable name refers to. In your `func2`, you are not doing that; you are only changing the contents of the object. `nums` still refers to the same list.

Answer (score 3):

It is of concept based on *mutable* and *immutable* objects in Python. In your case, for example:

```
a=[1,2]
def myfn():
    a=[3,4]
    print id(a)

>>>id(a)
3065250924L
>>>myfn()
3055359596
```

It is clear both are different objects. Now:

```
a=[1,2]
def myfn():
    a[:] =[3,4]
    print id(a)

>>>id(a)
3055358572
>>>myfn()
3055358572
```

That means it is same variable using in local and global scope.

Comment: That has nothing to do with mutability. It's a matter of mutating a value vs rebinding the value of a variable.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case it is because `list`s are *mutable*.

As a result having them in the *global namespace*, or even passed through a *function*, means that they will be changed as Python holds the reference to the mutable object, not a copy of it.

If you try the same thing with `tuple`s it will not work, as they are *immutable*.

The way to avoid this is to provide a copy of the list to the function, not the list itself:

```
func2(list[:])
```

At the same time you can do this with default arguments, where you can specify a default argument to be `[]`, and if you then `.append()` something to it, that default argument will forever hold that item within it for all future calls (unless you remove it in some way).

Answer (score 0):

- 2 variables `nums` are different and they  point to a same object or 2 different objects, though they have same name.
- when you call `func1(nums)`, mean that you pass a reference. Now the 2 variable `nums` point to same object. (**2 variables, 1 object**)
- when you assign in `func1`, the inside variable `nums` will point to a new object, the outside is still unchanged (**2 variables, 2 object**)
- and when you call `print nums` then this `nums` is the outside variable,

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for this result:

1. Variables are simply names that refer to objects
2. List is mutable

In `func1`,`nums` refer to a new object because a new list is created. Therefore `global nums` is not affected.

In `func2`, the modification is applied to the object passed in. Thus `global nums` is changed. A new object is not created because `list` is mutable.

ref: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python