# Why local variables referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made the two functions below in Python 3. The first function `test_list` works fine with the list `a` without error. I can modify the list element in that function.

However, the second funciton `test_int` will pop an error `local variable 'b' referenced before assignment`. Why can't I do this to the variable `b`?

```
a=[1,2,3]
def test_list():
    a[0]=2
    return a

b = 2
def test_int():
    b += 1
    return b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b += 1` is equivalent to `b = b.__iadd__(1)`; since the name `b` gets bound by that statement (l.h.s.), the compiler infers that `b` is a local variable; however, the r.h.s. expression contains the name `b` as well and thus you get the error *"local variable `'b'` referenced before assignment"* (the local name `b` doesn't refer to anything at the time when the expression is evaluated).

`a[0] = 2` on the other hand is equivalent to `a.__setitem__(0, 2)` and thus involves no name binding.

If you wish to modify a global name binding within a function, you can use the keyword [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#the-global-statement); there's also the equivalent [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#the-nonlocal-statement) for names contained in an outer, but not the global, scope.

Answer (score 3):

`b` is globally scoped. You are attempting to modify it in a local context, ie in `test_int`. You need the `global` keyword if you wish to modify a globally scoped variable in a local context. Read about variable scoping in python [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

The reason the first function `test_list` works is because you are not modifying the global variable itself, but only the contents. Here's a good explanation of what happens when you modify global variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31437415/14715054

This will fix your problem:

```py
a=[1,2,3]
def test_list():
    a[0]=2
    return a

b = 2
def test_int():
    global b
    b += 1
    return b
```