# Global variables: assignment vs method call

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, namespaces

To avoid accidentally modifying a global variable, python requires an explicit `global` statement before assigning to a global variable. However, modifying a global variable by calling its method can be done without any extra statement:

```
x = [1, 2]
y = [1, 2]
def f():
  global x
  x = x + [3] # won't affect global variable without global statement
  y.append(3) # will affect global variable without global statement
```

This seemed slightly inconsistent. Is this design choice made because it's considered less dangerous / less of a bad practice to modify global mutable objects through a method call, compared to replacing them with an entire new object? If so, why?

Comment: This helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329499/in-python-why-is-list-automatically-global

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

> In Python, **variables that are only referenced inside a function are
>   implicitly global**. **If a variable is assigned a value** anywhere
>   within the function’s body, **it’s assumed to be a local unless
>   explicitly declared as global**.

In your case `y` is referenced inside of the function, thus implicitly global. On the other hand, `x` is assigned a value, thus it must be local unless explicitly declared otherwise.

And the documentation goes further to answer your questions:

> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains
>   this. On one hand, **requiring global for assigned variables provides a
>   bar against unintended side-effects.** On the other hand, **if global was
>   required for all global references, you’d be using global all the
>   time.** You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in
>   function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would
>   defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying
>   side-effects.

Comment: Ah so it's not that changing `y` in my question is safe, it's just that it's too hard for python interpreter to cleanly distinguish it from the relatively safe cases of accessing components of imported modules?

Comment: I don't think it's only hard for the Python interpreter, but for any interpreter. Essentially there is no difference beyond the one we create in our own minds. `Global` is also fundamental to avoid name collisions, otherwise we'd have to create different names for every function we'd write.

Comment: This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really about mutability at the value level, which is how you're looking at it; it's about mutability of variable references, i.e. what a named item (a variable) is pointing at.

```python
x = [1, 2]
print(id(x)) # 57226944
y = [1, 2]
print(id(y)) # 57262728
def f():
  global x
  x = x + [3]
  print(id(x)) # 57306648 - CHANGED
  y.append(3)
  print(id(y)) # 57262728 - UNCHANGED

f()
```

Note that the name 'x' is now pointing at a new thing (a newly-created list), whereas the .append operation on y has not changed what the name 'y' is pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

In one sentence:

"without declaring it explicitly, python will not let you change the `reference` of a global variable".

Now let's explain what you have just read, assignment of object to a variable is actually making a `reference`, which is a memory address to where the object lays in the memory.

When we write:

```
x = [1, 2]
```

What actually happens that somewhere in the memory the list object is allocated with all its function references and members and other shit. This address is what actually kept in `x`.

We may use the function `id(object)` to notice the change:

```
x = [1, 2]
def foo():
 print id(x)    # an address like 50075016
 y = [1, 2, 3]
 print id(y)    # another address like 50075272 
 x = y          # won't work without declaring 'global x' 
                # because we try to change the address stored in x
                # from 50075016 to 50075272.
 x.append(3)    # works
 print id(x)    # same address 50075016
```

Comment: Of course, but I guess my question was why it's less of a risk to modify the object compared to changing which object the variable points to.