# Don't understand undefined reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

My understanding is that if I use a variable in a function without an assignment statement in the function, it will look "outside" the function for the variable.

This seems to be the case with a list, but not a simple variable.

In the following code I am told that the statement "aa += 1 contains an unresolved reference "aa", but the reference to bb[0] is just fine. Why is that?

```
aa = 0
bb = [9, 7]

def bbtest():
    aa += 1
    bb[0] += 1
```

Comment: What language are you using? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: python 3.8, using pycharm. running on a mac OS10.14.6

Comment: Could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6329536/1011724 - you're trying to rebind the name `aa` with the `+=` maybe?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit obscure, but there *is* a reason for this: When compiling a function, Python looks at all names used there and determines what scope they come from. Names that are not assigned to will use an outer scope (global or nonlocal), names that *are* assigned to are local. Since `aa += 1` counts as an assignment, it marks `aa` as a local variable.

While the next line looks similar, it is doing something different: Nowhere do you assign something *to the name `bb`*. You are retrieving something from the nonlocal/global name (the list), and are then assigning to an element of it.

You can fix this by explicitly marking `aa` as nonlocal or global:

```
def bbtest():
    global aa
    aa += 1
    bb[0] += 1
```

On the other hand, you can make the `bb` case fail by assigning to the name, *even afterwards*:

```
def bbtest():
    bb[0] += 1
    bb = "foo"
```

Comment: "You can fix this by explicitly marking aa as nonlocal or global:" --- or rather by passing in and then returning `aa` maybe? Great answer though btw.

Comment: @Dan Sure, that would probably be a better option. But you can fix Python's assumption that `aa` is local (which it isn't in this case) by using `global` or `nonlocal`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because in python you can only access the global variables, but cannot modify them inside the functions.
You can change the bb[0] value because of its something inside a global variable and not the var itself. 
Anyway, if you want it to work try to declare "global" in your function like this:

```
aa = 0
bb = [9, 7]

def bbtest():
    global aa
    aa += 1
    bb[0] += 1
```